# How to enable PHP support in TOMCAT 6 under CENTOS?

Tags: php, tomcat, centos

I am trying to make TOMCAT6 support PHP in CENTOS, but I don't know how, have been searching the solutions, but none of them works

Please advise

thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't Tomcat a Java engine? Can you use Apache instead? That's more traditional for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have both PHP and java running on my server, but with a different approach. I have apache running with a php interpreter, and then tomcat running seperately. I use mod_jk to create a vhost for tomcat, and obviously a regular vhost for php.

This means that you must have java and php running under different domains or subdomains, but can have them both on the same server.

Comment: Using mod_proxy you can use both indepently of subdomains.